# Moving a map down from universal cover

Tags: algebraic-topology

I know if I have a map $\mathbb{RP}^n\rightarrow X$ I can lift it to $S^n\rightarrow X$ if the lifting property is satisfied. When can I do it the other way around? That is, if I have a map $S^n\rightarrow X$ and want to construct something $\mathbb{RP}^n\rightarrow X$?

Comment: You have the whole "lift" think backwards. If we have $p: S^n \rightarrow \mathbb{RP}^n$ then you can lift $f:X \rightarrow \mathbb{RP}^n$ along $p$ to create a map $g:X \rightarrow S^n$ such that $p \circ g = f$ if the lifting citerion is satisfied. $g$ is called a lift of $f$ along $p$. You can always get a map $h':S^n \rightarrow X$ from a map $h:\mathbb{RP}^n \rightarrow X$ by precomposing with $p$. I.e $h' = h \circ p$.

Answer (score 1):

A map $f\colon S^n \to X$ induces a map $\widetilde{f}\colon \Bbb RP^n \to X$ provided $f(x) = f(-x)$ for all $x \in S^n$, in which case we have that $\widetilde{f}(\{x,-x\}) = f(x)$ is well defined.

There is nothing particular about $S^n$ and $\Bbb R P^n$ here, this is a general mechanism for quotients. If $\sim$ is an equivalence relation on a set $X$, a function $f\colon X \to Y$ induces a function $X/_{\sim} \to Y$ provided $f$ is constant on the equivalence classes of $\sim$ or, equivalently, constant on the fibers of the canonical projection $X \to X/_{\sim}$.  So the first paragraph is just this idea applied, recalling that $\Bbb R P^n$ can be defined as $S^n/_{\sim}$, where $x \sim y$ if $x = y$ or $x = -y$.